# Grails Layout, how to do that?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a grails app named qotd which has a controller named `quote`. I have written  view file for this controller named as `random.gsp` file as :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Random Quote</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="quote">
    <q>${content}</q>
    <p>${author}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now i have to write down the Grails Layout for this controller. For example i have to locate my .css and images files etc, how to do that(better if an example is shown)? And where i should place that file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a Grails application with `grails create-app qotd`, you get a file `grails-app/views/layout/main.gsp`. Take a look at that file, as it shows you how to include css, js and images. This file is the default Sitemesh layout file. To use it, change your random.gsp to

```
<head>
<meta name='layout' content='main'/>
<title>Random Quote</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="quote">
    <q>${content}</q>
    <p>${author}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then the layout file main.gsp will be wrapped around your content.
To learn more about Sitemesh, take a look at [chapter 7 in the Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#layouts)